# Error desglose IVA en facturas Odoo 12

Tags: odoo

He estado trabajando durante un tiempo en un servidor local para preparar mi Odoo, ahora he adquirido un servidor externo con la misma versión de Odoo.
Todo funciona idénticamente igual que en la otra, pero cuando voy a imprimir una factura no me desglosa el IVA, me lo cuanta todo como uno (en el servidor interno si funciona correctamente)
Alguna idea de dónde puede estar el problema??

imagen del reporte echo a través de nuevo servidor (no desglosa el iva):
[image: Servidor nuevo (no funciona)]

imagen del reportes echo desde el servidor local:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay que remarcar que estoy usando el mismo pedido y la misma bdd (una copia) en los dos servidores.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es debido a tu configuración de Impuestos y los grupos de impuestos. Puede que se haya perdido. Pero si los agregas en el mismo grupo en la factura se veran en 1 sola linea. Sin embargo si los dejas en varios grupos o sin un grupo asignado, se mostraran en varias lineas.

[image: Aca esta la vista de configuracion de impuestos en Contabilidad>Configuracion>Impuestos]

Solamente tienes que cambiar los grupos de impuestos o asignarle uno completamente distinto (O crearlos)

[image: Aca un ejemplo ya impreso en PDF de un presupuesto con distintos tipos de impuestos]